# IntelliJ IDEA 15 not generating .class files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a java EE project (basically Maximo 7.5 customization).
I was previously using Eclipse and everything worked fine.
I recently tired using IntelliJ IDEA 15 Ultimate edition. I set the project but when I build. It doesnt generate any .class files.
I am however, given the following errors.

1. Error:osgi: [Maximo] Missing file on classpath: C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/workspace/Maximo/out/production/Maximo
2. Warning:osgi: [Maximo] The JAR is empty: The instructions for the JAR named compile-server did not cause any content to be included, this is likely wrong

May be I don't know how to set up a Java EE project in IntelliJ.
What other info should I paste about Project Structure which can help in troubleshooting the issue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an issue with adding required Libraries and Java version being used. 
I again re imported the project and added the required libraries.
It started compiling class files but when I deployed those class files on servers they didn't work. 
I then configured the JDK to use proper language level for compilation for this project (Jave 6). Now everything working fine.
Thanks a lot for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

See [this documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/developing-a-java-ee-application.html) on JetBrains website. It sounds like the importing of the Eclipse project has gone wrong and you're missing some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today (May 4, 2023). Intellij was not generating a .class file. Everything else was there except the class files. After moving the directory and trying different SDKs without any success, the solution was to click on "Repair IDE". At the time my folders were on a removable hard drive. I had the directory folders open when I clicked this option, and I saw the .class being created instantly and my code started working.

In another instance, the bug was a simple syntax error `public void main(String args)`, did you catch it? this allowed for the .java file to be created and a .class to appear in the side menu within IntelliJ CE but no .class file creation on the libraries. The syntax error was a missing squared/array brackets inside the arguments declaration of the main method.  While IntelliJ was creating the .java file, these missing brackets did not allow for the .java file to compile properly so a .class file was not created. Once I replaced the brackets, I recompiled the class and it all worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Since the previous edit removed these specific statements, I'd like to point out that my mentioning of Jesus Christ and Christmas are clearly statements of joy and gratitude, and should not constitute a concern for anyone who doesn't care for these personal matters of faith. I find it rude then, and an attack on my faith, to have these statements removed when they do not subtract from the technical helpfulness of my answer to the question.

Comment: Hi there. It's not so much that [religious references are not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295810/do-we-allow-religious-invocations-in-questions-answers), it's that technical writing is a requirement. Thus, any topics that might appear in casual writing (that one might pen for social media) tend to get edited out here. If you are not familiar with _Meta Stack Overflow_, I do recommend it - there is a large canon of community-emergent rules that are not fully codified.

Comment: You have not made use of your profile, where there is a wide permission to write nearly whatever you like. People of faith sometimes use their profile for that purpose, and you'd be welcome to do so too.

Comment: Thank you @halfer, but I have to reiterate that this is not an attempt to evangelize, being thankful to Jesus is natural to me, and I am not sure how being thankful to Jesus  may constitute a religious attempt at anything. However, I do concede per your explanation that it may seem casual, and the specific expression of thankfulness was hearty and casual indeed. Thanks for your clarification, I’ll be mindful of this.